# sudo throw error cannot execute binary file exec format error

Tags: linux, permissions, rstudio, sudo, cpu-architecture

I made a mistake while trying to install Rstudio in a debian with this command:

> sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.2.5033-amd64.deb

and now if I try to use sudo again, I ve got this message :

> sudo apt-get update:
>    bash: /usr/bin/sudo : cannot execute binary file:
>   Exec format error

How can I reverse this error ?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably ask this sysadmin question on https://unix.stackexchange.com/.  You might need to boot into a recovery environment if you overwrote `sudo`, or if you broke `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` or something.  Unless you have a statically-linked build of sudo, e.g. from busybox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I manage to fix it, here is what I've done,

login to root with `su`,
remove the alter version of `sudo` with: `apt-get remove sudo:amd64`
reinstall the correct version: `apt-get install sudo`
exit root mode and try it gain, now it works.

thanks